# React Native expo-image-picker for sdk 46 assetId type

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

In expo-image-picker the type of assetId is of type string | null | undefined and it says

```
This might be null when the ID is unavailable or the user gave limited permission to access the media library. On Android, the ID is unavailable when the user selects a photo by directly browsing file system.
```

What does it mean in practice? How much can I be sure that this ID would be present since in expo-image-picker in pickImage handler there is a comment that no permissions are necessary

```
const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });

    console.log(result);

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
    }
  };
```

is user able to pick the image directly from the file system? How much can I be sure that this id will be present? Or should I derive it from the uri?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

please check your Expo Go version.